# how to synchronize vehicles to the GPS clock

Tags: c++, omnet++, veins

I wanna know how can I add a GPS receiver into vehicles in veins/sumo simulation to be able to synchronize all the cars in my simulation with the 1PPS (one Pulse Per Sencond) signal received from GPS.
 thank you

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Be sure to take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and visit the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help). Generally a question here attracts more attention and better answers if it shows some prior research and, even better, has actual code that is not working. What have you tried?